# SQL add a table to SQL query without Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am a newbie to SQL so I'm sure this is an easy one...
I am using a query builder to build a query.
I have 2 tables linked by 2 primary keys which exist in each table. This **Query 1** is working fine and the results are as expected, but I am trying to add a Table 3 to the query but this table has no primary key that can be linked with any key in either of Table 1 or Table 2.
Is there any way to link Table 3 to output data without affecting the number of rows displayed from **Query 1**?

Thanks all in advance

Comment: maybe you can give some screenshot of your table schema

Comment: Primary keys are there to ensure data quality. They aren't really needed/used when joining tables. You can join tables without primary keys.

Comment: Query 1 has 2840 results from the linked primary keys in Table 1 and Table 2.but when I add Table 3 without linking to Table 1 or Table 2 the results are 100,000+.So the result I want is a query to include Table 1,2 and 3 to give results of 2840

Comment: It would help if you could add sample data as text to the question or to sqlfiddle.

Comment: Gotta see the schema -- not a screenshot, rather text.

Comment: thanks guys for all the responses but was able to add another table with the provided primary keys needed to link all the tables correctly.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as answer. You can accept it after minimal time to show you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is a SELECT you could just add Table3 to your query and use it in your SELECT, like

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3 FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table 3 t3
```